# Installing pywinrm on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python2.7 installed on my ubuntu machine. 
But when I'm trying to install pywinrm package using `pip install pywinrm`, I'm getting below error.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
    raise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

How can I install?

Answer (score 0):

You can try install by download file [here](https://pypi.org/project/pywinrm/#files) and after that `pip install pywinrm-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

```
                `
```

Comment: Try: pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: And after that: pip install pywinrm